# navigator not found in javascript-birt report

Tags: javascript, birt

I am implementing javascript in birt to check the os of the machine as I am making a responsive report.

Here is my javascript

```
if(navigator.userAgent.match(/Android/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/webOS/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPad/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/BlackBerry/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/Windows Phone/i)){

var a = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
    var i =0;
    for (i = 0;i< a.length;i++) 
    {
        a[i].style.width = '384px';
    }

    a = document.getElementsByTagName('embed');
     i =0;
    for (i = 0;i< a.length;i++) 
    {
        a[i].width = '384px';
        a[i].initialWidth = '384px';
    }
}
```

It gives me following error when I load it on the browser

ReferenceError: "navigator" is not defined. `(/report/method[@name="beforeRender"]#1)`

Answer (score 0):

`navigator` is a property of the `window` object in a web browser.  You only have access to it in a javascript file *running in a web browser*.